# При возвращении IEnumerable из контроллера не перехватывается Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp

Есть метод в контроллере который возвращает IEnumerable,
в процессе конвейера LINQ происходит Exception и фильтр эксепшенов не перехватывает этот эксепшен и клиенту приходит поломанный массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<int> Get() {

        var a = new[] {
            1,
            2,
            3
        };


        return a.Select(x => {
            if (x == 3) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return x;
        });
    }
}
```

Как сделать так что бы экспешен был перехвачен Exception фильтром? И пользователю не передавалось бы некорректных данных?

Comment: Добавить `ToList()/ToArray()` и возвращать, соответственно, список/массив?

Comment: @Alexandr Petrov И запускать конвейер раньше того времени когда он действительно понадобится?

Comment: А вы собираетесь по частям вычитывать ответ сервера?

Comment: Ответ клиенту нужен целиком. У меня тогда вопрос что быстрее toarray или tolist?

Answer (score 1):

Для перехвата таких исключение надо использовать *middleware*. Но даже если вы его перехватите у вас все равно будет мало возможности, что то сделать. Дело в том, что это исключение возникает когда движок Asp уже начал писать в поток HttpResponse. А это означает, что все заголовки уже записаны и свойство [HttpResponse.HasStarted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.hasstarted?view=aspnetcore-2.2) взведено. И единственое что остается этот писать в конец тела ответа.

Как решить просто:

- Использовать `ToList()/ToArray()`.
- Если исключение возникает на пример при подключении к базе, то
  попытаться открыть подключение за ранние.

Как решить сложно:

Можно подсунуть свой стрим в тело *HttpResponse*. Это довольно не стандартный путь и его стоит использовать ну если совсем припекло. Вдобавок метод конечно не эффективен в плане производительности, не позволяет переписывать заголовки и не очень красив, но работает.

```
class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originStream = context.Response.Body;

        try {
            using (var tmpStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                try {
                    context.Response.Body = tmpStream;
                    await _next(context);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    tmpStream.SetLength(0);
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Message);
                    tmpStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                }

                tmpStream.Position = 0;
                await tmpStream.CopyToAsync(originStream);
            }
        }
        finally {
            context.Response.Body = originStream;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Вариант со стримом по сути ничем не отличается от ToList - коллекция все так же вычитывается целиком, и в тот же момент, после того, как контроллер сделал свою работу, но до начала записи в Response Stream. Только обработка ошибок стандартная работать не будет.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну в принципе я согласен, Но разница все таки есть... 1) Если обработка ошибок своя это  ни чего не сломает 2) Свой стрим позволяет делать пул(RecyclableMemoryStream), с ToList такое сложно сделать.